# Memory leak related to CGDataProviderCopyData

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, core-graphics, ios7

I use this function to know if my picture contains pixel of a certain color :

---

```
     - (BOOL)imageHasOrange:(UIImage *)img
     {
           CGImageRef imageRef = img.CGImage;

    NSData *data = (__bridge NSData *)  CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef));

           unsigned char *pixels = (unsigned char *)[data bytes];

           BOOL hasColor = NO;

           for(int i = 0; i < [data length]; i += 4)
           {
                if(pixels[i] == 255 && pixels[i+1] == 132 && pixels[i+2] == 0)
                {
                   hasColor = YES;
                   break;
                }
           }

           CFRelease(imageRef);

           return hasColor;

      }
```

---

When i use Instruments to trace memory leaks, it said it is related to CGDataProviderCopyData function.

But i use ARC so i don't need to release my "data" array right ?

Comment: ARC does not manage Core Foundation objects for you.

Comment: So which object should i release ? and how ? as i can't do [object release]

Comment: I did : CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef);  and CFRelease(provider); after, but i still get a memory leak from CGImageGetDataProvider

Comment: @JeanFrançoisManatane: `&data` isn't an object; it's the address of a variable. `data`, however, does refer to an object.

Answer (score 5):

`CGDataProviderCopyData` returns an ownership, like its name says: *Copy* functions are among those [so documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html).

So, you own that data object.

ARC does not manage CF objects by default, and a `__bridge` cast does not change ARC's memory management of an object: it will not cause ARC to retain the object nor to release it.

Thus, because you used `__bridge`, you are still obliged to release the data.

Option 1 is to uphold your obligation and release the data yourself, by calling `CFRelease((__bridge CFDataRef)data)`.

Option 2 is to tell ARC “here, dispose of this when I'm done with it”. To do that, you need to use a `__bridge_transfer` cast to transfer management of the object to ARC.

**Choose only one of these options.** If you transfer management of the object to ARC, *don't* release it yourself—the transfer means that you no longer need to do that; you've transferred that responsibility to ARC.

---

While we're on the subject of releasing things: **You do not need to, and should not, release `imageRef`.** The UIImage owns that and you don't. You will cause a crash if you release it out from under the UIImage that owns it.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSData *data = (__bridge_transfer NSData *)CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually releasing the CGImageRef instead of your copy of CGDataRef
What you can do, is create a separate CGDataRef object, copy data into it and then 
Release it when you are done with your data Like this.

```
CFDataRef theData; 
theData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef));
NSData *data = (__bridge NSData *)theData; 

//.. do some stuff 

//Releaase data 

CFRelease(theData);
```